# Union of Streaming Dataframe and Batch Dataframe in Spark Structured Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

How can I combine streaming dataframe and batch dataframe together in Spark Structured Streaming ?

Comment: "combine" as in "join", or "combine" as in "union" ?

Answer (score 2):

You can do normal join:

```
val stream = spark.readStream(....)
val batch = spark.read....

val joinSandB = stream.join(batch, "someColumn")
```

See more in [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#join-operations)